# How to make gwt-maven-plugin to parse jetty-env.xml

Tags: gwt, maven, jetty

I'm using gwt-maven-plugin, version 1.2 with GWT version 2.0.3. When I run it in hosted mode (Jetty) I can't get it to load my jetty-env.xml file.

Any clues about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that GWT and Maven plugin versions the embedded jetty igonres thw file /WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml, but same information can be used in the file /WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml.

So, renaming the file from "jetty-env.xml" to "jetty-web.xml" solved the issue.